# Validation, how it make in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have two main fields. `Pesel` and `Nip`.

But if one is filled the other does not have to be filled.

For Example, If I complete the field `Nip`, I don't have to fill field `Pesel`, but I can do it.

```
$("#form1").validate({
  submitHandler:function(form) {
  SubmittingForm();

},
   rules: {
      imie: "required", 
      adres_email: {                // compound rule
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      nazwisko: {                // compound rule
        required: true,
      },
      sid: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 9,
        sid:true
      },
       pesel: {
         minlength: 11,
         pesel:true
       },
       nip: {
         required: true
       },
   }

   });
   });
</script>
```

I download it from the link: [bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation)

Comment: what is the plugin you are using?

Comment: I downloaded from this page : http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 2):

Based on [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method), you will need to use `require_from_group` method, where you will need to assign `pesel` and `nip` to a group in common:

```
//script narrowed to the issue
$( "#form1" ).validate({
  rules: {
    pesel: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".example-group"]
    },
    nip: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".example-group"]
    }
  }
});
```

In this [example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2d22m/) I've set up, we have this form:

```
<form id="myform">
  <label for="pesel">Pesel: </label>
  <input class="left example-group" id="pesel" name="pesel">
  <br/>
  <label for="nip">Nip: </label>
  <input class="left example-group" id="nip" name="nip">
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Validate!" />
 </form>
```

Notice the class provided to script `.example-group` which will tell what combo of fields will have the feature (`nip` + `pesel` in the case).

**EDIT:** 
http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js must be included

Comment: I did it as above, but still doesn't work.
My code : http://pastebin.com/MQSLZr9a

Comment: are the other validations working? have you included http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js ?